# update object with pre_save signal subquery django

Tags: django, subquery, signals

i need to display previous balance of users , i have used pre save signal to assign to the old balance before the transaction happens

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client_seller = models.ForeignKey(ClientSeller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    type_of_payment = models.CharField(choices=type_of_payment,max_length=60,default=retrieve)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2)
    previous_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3,blank=True,default=0)

class ClientSeller(models.Model):
   admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
   balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=30,default=0)
```

i need to assign `previous_balance` in `Payment` to `balance` in `ClientSeller` , balance in `ClientSeller` i change every time , but i need to show the users what was previous balance when a transaction happens

```
def pre_save_balance(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    if not instance.pk:

        Payment.objects.update(
            previous_balance = Subquery(
            Payment.objects.filter(client_seller__name=instance.client_seller.name).annotate(
               pre_balance=F('client_seller__balance')
            ).values('pre_balance')[:1]
            )
            )
```

pre_save.connect(pre_save_balance,sender=Payment)

but it only show the default `previous_balance` value which is 0 !?
is there something i have missed ? or not understanding in `pre_save` signal good ?!
thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

Every time you're getting the first payment you made and maybe then the seller had 0 balance. You need to order your queryset and  use the `latest()` method in order to gey the latest payment.

So you need to add something like `.latest('payment_date')` in your Subquery and lose the [:1] at the end.